# C++ symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 in xCode

Tags: c++, xcode, linker-errors

I'm trying to implement template for stack however error occurred when compiling.

This is my `Stack.h` file

```
const int MAX_STACK = 2;

enum STATE { OK = 0, STACK_FULL, STACK_EMPTY };

template <class T>
class Stack
{
public:
    Stack();

    void Clear();
    int Push(T x);
    int Pop(T * w);
    int StackState();

private:
    T t[MAX_STACK];
    int top;
};
```

and my `Stack.cpp` file

```
#include "Stack.h"

template<class T>
Stack<T>::Stack():
top(0) {}

template<class T>
void Stack<T>::Clear()
{
    top = 0;
}

template<class T>
int Stack<T>::Push(T x)
{
    if (top < MAX_STACK)
    {
        t[top++] = x;
        return OK;
    }
    else
    {
        return STACK_FULL;
    }
}

template<class T>
int Stack<T>::Pop(T * w)
{
    if (top > 0)
    {
        *w = t[--top];
        return OK;
    }
    else
    {
        return STACK_EMPTY;
    }
}

template<class T>
int Stack<T>::StackState()
{
    switch (top)
    {
        case 0:
            return STACK_EMPTY;
        case MAX_STACK:
            return STACK_FULL;
        default:
            return OK;
    }
}
```

Test program in `Main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Stack.h"

int main()
{
    Stack<char *> stack;

    char tab[3] = { 'V', 'E', 'R' };

    std::cout << "Inserting into stack:\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if (stack.StackState() != STACK_FULL)
        {
            std::cout << "Trying to insert " << tab[i] << ",\n";
            stack.Push(&tab[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Stack is full!\n";
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\n\nDeleting items from stack: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        char ** z;

        if (stack.Pop(z) == OK)
        {
            std::cout << "Deletion successful: " << **z << "\n";
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However getting this error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Stack<char*>::StackState()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "Stack<char*>::Pop(char**)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "Stack<char*>::Push(char*)", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "Stack<char*>::Stack()", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Thank you for ideas.